# validation of webservice answer throws "An incorrect X.509 Token Type is detected" exception

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, ws-security

So I am implementing a SOAP service with SSL and signed content. The service owner provided a WSDL and a policy XML for webservice security (WSS). The webservice security is handled by CXF 2.7.15. The policy file is referenced in the endpoint and client configuration of the spring context.

I can send a request and receive an answer. But while trying to validate the WSS header the following exception is thrown:

```
org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: These policy alternatives can not be satisfied: 
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}X509Token: An incorrect X.509 Token Type is detected
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionInfoMap.checkEffectivePolicy(AssertionInfoMap.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyVerificationInInterceptor.handle(PolicyVerificationInInterceptor.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AbstractPolicyInterceptor.handleMessage(AbstractPolicyInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:849)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1626)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1515)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1317)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:223)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:632)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:572)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:481)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:136)
```

The policy file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsp:Policy
wsu:Id='Sig'
xmlns:wsu='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd'
xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy
  http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/ws-securitypolicy.xsd
  http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy
  http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/ws-policy.xsd  ">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
    <wsp:All>
        <sp:AsymmetricBinding xmlns:sp='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy'>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:InitiatorToken>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient'>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:WssX509V3Token10 />
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:X509Token>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:InitiatorToken>
                <sp:RecipientToken>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Always'>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:WssX509V3Token10 />
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:X509Token>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:RecipientToken>
                <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:Basic256 />
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                <sp:Layout>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:Strict />
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:Layout>
                <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody />
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
        <sp:Wss10 xmlns:sp='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy'>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:MustSupportRefEmbeddedToken />
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:Wss10>
        <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy'>
            <sp:Body />
        </sp:SignedParts>
    </wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
```

The header of the sent request:

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-IDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-BF463C6BF1D93A74AC14297178534515">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                    <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="soap"/>
                </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                <ds:Reference URI="#_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList=""/>
                        </ds:Transform>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
                    <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

And the header of the answer:

```
    <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <ds:Signature Id="Signature-9821" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                <ds:Reference URI="#id-9822">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo Id="KeyId-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STRId-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                    <ds:X509Data>
                        <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                            <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=XXXX,OU=XXXX,O=XXX,L=XXXX,ST=XXXXX,C=XX</ds:X509IssuerName>
                            <ds:X509SerialNumber>XXXXXXXXX</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                        </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                    </ds:X509Data>
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

---

Edit May 6th, 20015:

So, after debugging the X509TokenPolicyValidator (as suggested by Colm) with an incoming response, we found the following:

- the `bstResults` is empty
- `signedResults` contains one value
- the referenceType is `ISSUER_SERIAL`, **not** `KEY_IDENTIFIER` (line 172, ->> x509-reference-type=ISSUER_SERIAL)
- the `signatureElement` will be null (line 175, ->> token-element=[ds:Signature: null])

CodeSnippet of X509TokenPolicyValidator.java:

```
168         // Maybe the X.509 token was included as a KeyIdentifier
169         if (X509_V3_VALUETYPE.equals(requiredType)) {
170             for (WSSecurityEngineResult result : signedResults) {
171                 STRParser.REFERENCE_TYPE referenceType = 
172                     (STRParser.REFERENCE_TYPE)result.get(WSSecurityEngineResult.TAG_X509_REFERENCE_TYPE);
173                 if (STRParser.REFERENCE_TYPE.KEY_IDENTIFIER == referenceType) {
174                     Element signatureElement = 
175                         (Element)result.get(WSSecurityEngineResult.TAG_TOKEN_ELEMENT);
176                     Element keyIdentifier = getKeyIdentifier(signatureElement);
177                     if (keyIdentifier != null 
178                         && X509_V3_VALUETYPE.equals(keyIdentifier.getAttributeNS(null, "ValueType"))) {
179                         try {
180                             X509Security token = 
181                                 new X509Security(keyIdentifier, 
182                                                  new BSPEnforcer(true));
183                             X509Certificate cert = token.getX509Certificate(null);
184                             if (cert != null && cert.getVersion() == 3) {
185                                 return true;
186                             }
187                         } catch (WSSecurityException e) {
188                             LOG.log(Level.FINE, e.getMessage());
189                         }
190                     }
191                 }
192             }
193         }
194         return false;
```

The `signedResult`:

```
[{signature-value=[B@259d5279, subject=null, canonicalization-method=http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#, public-key=null, x509-certificates=[Ljava.security.cert.X509Certificate;@3c9e169f, signature-method=http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1, secret=null, principal=CN=xxx, OU=xxx, O=xxx, L=xxx, ST=xxx, C=xxx, data-ref-uris=[org.apache.wss4j.dom.WSDataRef@20326436], x509-reference-type=ISSUER_SERIAL, x509-certificate=[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx], validated-token=true, action=2, id=Signature-3289, token-element=[ds:Signature: null]}, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

Answer (score 0):

The certificate in the BinarySecurityToken is likely not a "v3" X509Certificate (as indicated by the "WssX509V3Token10" policy), but a "v1".

Colm.

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, Windows as well as keytool both report V3 certificates for every cert involved. They differ in their extensions, though. Do I need a special extension / extension value to allow digital signatures?

Comment: No special extensions are required. I've tested a similar message with the latest CXF code and it works fine. The logic for verifying certificates is given here, maybe you could set a breakpoint and figure out what is going on?https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cxf.git;a=blob;f=rt/ws/security/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/ws/security/wss4j/policyvalidators/X509TokenPolicyValidator.java;h=8a3feb272d75079c4f0c1782e1ed04922c1e7337;hb=HEAD

Comment: We debugged the class. I edited the original question with the results. It's pretty much unexplainable from our point of view. Maybe you can make some sense of it?

Comment: Ok I see what the problem is. IMO the service response is incorrect. The service policy specifies that the RecipientToken must "always" be included in the request (and referenced via IssuerSerial). However there is no BinarySecurityToken in the service response (or KeyIdentifier containing the certificiate). IssuerSerial is just a way of referencing the certificate, and can't be viewed as an "inclusion".

Comment: That was the case, thank you. If you want to post that as an answer then I will gladly accept it.